# holes-in-her-purse bail meaning

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language, informal-language

In Breaking bad, when Hank was up against Walt, after everyone else was "out" in the game, he said the following:

> When old holes-in-her-purse bails, you know you're in deep.

I know of money burning a hole in your pocket. Is this is a synonym of the expression?

One of the meanings of bail is to abandon a commitment. Does the expression refer to the fact that her purse holes (I take them as the pockets in her purse) bail (don't produce money anymore), you are in deep (in trouble)?

Answer (score 0):

The expression "holes-in-her-purse" is a person. It is a person who Walt believes has (metaphorical) holes in her purse.  It is someone who never has cash, a spendthrift or wasteful person.  The adjective "old" is being used casually and suggests "someone who we have known for a long time". If you know the series you will know who she is.

So the whole expression means something like

> When that woman, who we know well, and who never has cash because she wastes money, gives up and walks away from our commitment, then you know that you are in a lot of trouble that it will be difficult to escape from.

Comment: I haven't watched the series, just the clip with the line. I think this takes place in a poker game in response to one player, a woman, throwing in her hand. She's "baiiling," i.e., quitting the betting on her hand. Could it be that she's usually willing to bluff against long odds because she's always broke, but in this case, the odds are too long for even her?

Comment: You have not explained “bails” but you have explained that “old Holes-in-her-purse” is the nickname of a person. Your rephrasing of the sentence makes a number of assumptions about the situation that are unlikely. User105719 may be right about his different assumptions but really all Bahram needs to know is about the unusual nickname and what “bails” means colloquially.

Comment: Please then write an answer.

Comment: _Old holes-in-her-purse_ is not necessarily a nickname: it might be, but it might also be the only time anybody has ever referred to her in this way. (I don't know the series, so I have no idea).